# Closing child window from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I cant figure out why this won't work. Is there something wrong with this code? The function is being called I checked with an alert but it just won't close the window.

```
 $('#click').click(function() {
   var win = window.open("test3.html","something","width=550,height=170");
 });

 function closeit(){
   win.close();
 }
```

and on test3.html

```
 window.opener.closeit();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `win` variable is scoped to the function that handles the click event. Put it in a scope shared by both that function and `closeit`.

In this case, that would probably look like:

```
var win;

…

    $('#click').click(function() {
        win = window.open("test3.html", "something", "width=550,height=170");
    });
});

function closeit() {
    win.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first `win` is a local variable in the callback scope, while the second is a global object. Move the definition (`var win`) to outside the function and it should work.