# Pop up window getting closed even when mouse pointer is at the top of the popup window

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, popup

I want to implement popup functionality for a page, for which I used the below code.

```
 <input type="button" value="Open a Popup Window" onclick="window.open('WebForm2.aspx','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
```

using this I was able to open a new window. but also I have to close the popup window if the user moves the cursor (i.e onmouseout) from the popup window and also I want to close the popup when user clicks the X button on the right corner of the tab. For that what I did was

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function alertUser() {
            window.close();
        }
    </script>

<div onmouseout ="alertUser()"> My contents ... </div>.
```

Now my problem is when the cursor is moved near the close btn without clicking the window is closed. What can be done?

Comment: Can I close the child window by clicking on its parent window.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `onmouseout` listener is on the `div`. When the mouse leaves the `div`, `window.close()` is triggered. There isn't any way to listen for events on application chrome (like the title bar of the window), so there's not much you can do. You can style the `div` so that it takes up the entire content area of the window, but that's about it. You can also consider changing your design so that leaving the window/div doesn't cause it to close. That could be startling behavior for a user, anyhow.

Comment: Can I close child window by clicking on its parent window.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125577/closing-child-window-from-parent-window You can assign the opened window to a variable and then close it on some action in the parent.

Comment: Thanks!!.. Ok fine, I looked the page and understood the way to call. but now my question is where can the function closeit() be called.? is it in the clickevent of div. Could you plese help me on that?