# Close child window from parent and retrieve data

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a web application that opens a login window for Spotify login. After login, I am trying to close the child window from the parent component and trying to retrieve the parameters from the child window's URL. But the close function for child is not working.

Also, when I am trying to print `params` in the component HTML it shows nothing

That is the code that I am using

**Login Component HTML**

```
<a href="#" (click)="login($event)">Login</a>
Child Params: {{ params }}  //Not showing anything
```

**Login Component**

```
private params: ISpotifyAuth | null;
private popup: Window | undefined;


ngOnInit(): void {
    const hash = window.location.search.substr(1);
    if (hash !== '' && hash !== undefined) {
        this.spotifyCallback(hash);
    }
}


login(event: MouseEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const scopes = [
            'user-read-currently-playing',
            'user-read-recently-played',
            'user-read-playback-state',
            'user-top-read',
            'user-read-private',
            'user-read-email',
            'user-modify-playback-state'
        ];
        const url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${
            environment.spotify.clientID
        }&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${
            environment.spotify.redirectUrl
        }&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&show_dialog=true&state=34fFs29kd09`;

        const width = 550;
        const height = 650;
        const y = window.top.outerHeight / 2 + window.top.screenY - width / 2;
        const x = window.top.outerWidth / 2 + window.top.screenX - height / 2;

        this.popup = window.open(
            url,
            'Login with Spotify',
            `toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=${width}, height=${height}, top=${y}, left=${x}`
        ) as Window;
}


spotifyCallback(payload: any){
    this.popup?.close();  // Not working
    console.log(payload);  // Not working
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closing child window from parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125577/closing-child-window-from-parent-window)

Comment: @Yannick Eich I have already done this, can you please check the code snippet

Comment: What do "_Not working_"s mean? The pop-up window is not closed and nothing is logged into console?

Comment: @Teemu, yes. In the `spotifyCallback` function, I have added a console and tried to close the window that I have opened. But it is not working.

Comment: @Teemu, Lol, I have clearly mentioned this in the post. Tried to close the login window and trying to print the data I have stored in the params variable(which I am getting from child window's url) in my component html